# React component not receiving intermediate state when chaining actions in redux-saga

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga

I have two actions `TEST` and `TEST_DONE` which both increment an `id` property in my redux state.  I am using redux-saga to dispatch the second action `TEST_DONE` automatically whenever I dispatch the first action `TEST` from my component.

I expect the order of execution to go like this:

1. component renders with initial value of `testState.id` = `0`
2. component dispatches `TEST` action
3. component re-renders with `testState.id` = `1`
4. saga dispatches the `TEST_DONE` action
5. component re-renders with `testState.id` = `2`

Instead my component only re-renders when `testState.id` is updated to `2`.  I can't see the `1` value in the `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` function.  It shows `0` as the previous prop.

**Why does the prop jump from `0` to `2` without receiving `1` in between?**

---

saga.js:

```
export function* TestSagaFunc() {
    yield put({
        type: actions.TEST_DONE
    });
};

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        yield takeEvery(actions.TEST, TestSagaFunc),
    ]);
};
```

action.js:

```
const actions = {
    TEST: 'TEST',
    TEST_DONE: 'TEST_DONE',

    callTest: (id) => ({
        type: actions.TEST,
        payload: {
            id
        }
    }),
};
export default actions;
```

reducer.js:

```
const initState = {
    testState:  {
        id: 0
    }
};

export default function TestReducers ( state=initState, { type, ...action}) {
    switch(type) {
    default:
        return state;
    case actions.TEST: {
        const { id } = state.testState;
        const nextId = id + 1;
        return {
            ...state,
            testState: {
                ...state.testState,
                id: nextId
            }
        };
    };
    case actions.TEST_DONE: {
        const { id } = state.testState;
        const nextId = id + 1;
        return {
            ...state,
            testState: {
                ...state.testState,
                id: nextId
            }
        };
    }
};
};
```

console output from component `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`

[image: Image of result]

Comment: The state is indeed being updated as you've seen, but component renders are not guaranteed to happen on every state change. Try importing `delay` from `redux-saga/effects` and `yield delay(1000);` before calling `yield put` in `TestSagaFunc` so the two state updates don't get batched together.

Comment: @azundo Thanks for your response, you are right. I try importing as you said, but I think it just is a trick. Do you have anything else to deal with it thoroughly?

Comment: Yes, this is just a trick. If you need the intermediate state to be rendered you could dispatch your second action from the component being rendered with a `useEffect` (or `componentDidUpdate` to ensure that the component went through one render cycle with the updated state. But there is no way to force your component to render intermediate reducer states which are updating in between render cycles here.

Comment: That is my lack of knowledge about redux-saga. The saga helps us handle the side effects, but my test is not. The information you shared is very helpful and I resolved my issue. Thank you so much @azundo

Comment: @azundo I had to read this question and your comment a few times in order to get what you are saying.  My first thought was “the component definitely re-renders when the redux state changes”.  But I see here that we are talking about an *intermediate* change which is immediately overwritten.  So this comes down to how React batches updates which is not something that I understand deeply enough to explain.

Comment: I think I will edit the question to highlight the issue more clearly.  You should write your two comments into an answer.

Comment: Thanks @LindaPaiste, let me know if I'm summarized them well of if I can clarify better!

Comment: @azundo looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing my comments from the question:

The redux state is indeed being updated as you've seen, but a component is not guaranteed to render every intermediate state change based on the way react batches state changes. To test this you can try importing `delay` from `redux-saga/effects` and adding `yield delay(1000);` before calling `yield put` in `TestSagaFunc` so the two state updates don't get batched together.

This is just a trick to illustrate the effects of batching and almost certainly not what you want to do. If you need the intermediate state to be rendered you could dispatch `TEST_DONE` from the component being rendered with a `useEffect` (or `componentDidUpdate`) to ensure that the component went through one render cycle with the intermediate state. But there is no way to force your component to render intermediate reducer states that are batched together.